# How to add styles to wordpress default menu

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just installed my theme to newly installed wordpress site. I didn't create any menu from appearence>menus, so by default wordpress showing "home" * "sample page" to the header as a default menu (I don't know the correct name, maybe callback menu?)

the problem is they are not getting any style from my stylesheet, I know if I create my custom menu, they ll get the styles from css. but I want this default wordpress menu to get the css as well. so the theme doesn't look odd when first install. how to do it?

[image]

Comment: By which code have you added you stylesheet ?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default styling of the WP menu looks like this:

```
<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2">
                <a href="">Sample Page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

You should be able to style the elements of the menu on your page using the appropriate classes in your `style.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

create a menu by name "primary" in apperance -> menus, and assign menus under it and u can refer
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu 
or else use this in header.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary'))?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, creat new menu area in your theme.
For this, once (if you didn't set it) allow menus in your theme with this function:

```
add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
```

After this, add new menu your theme with this function:

```
register_nav_menu('primary', 'Our first menu');
```

And add your header.php lastly for print your custom menu:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) { $menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'echo' => '0', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); $menuOutput = preg_replace( array( '#^<ul[^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#' ), '', $menu ); echo $menuOutput; } else { }
```

This output is same as:

```
<li class="menu-item some-class">
  <a>Sample page</a>
</li>
```

Use   
And CSS it!

```
ul.your-class{}
ul.your-class li{list-style:square}
ul.your-class li a{ color:red }
```

Answer (score -2):

Normally the default menu is called in the `header.php` with the function `wp_nav_menu()`. You can add CSS classes as arguments to `wp_nav_menu()`. If you are unaware of that the please refer to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu.

Comment: my theme is calling the `style.css` I 've checked it! I created the theme myself, so I didn't add any style for the default menu. so that is the question, how do I add my custom menu styles to the default wordpress menu?

when I use my custom menu, it is getting the styles from my `style.css` so I'm sure style sheet is loading fine, but I want to know how do I add this style to default wordpress menu too?